# The Mix manifest does not exist - Laravel Fortify Jetstream Login/Registration Issue when deploying laravel in Hostgator shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-mix, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I have been able to deploy Laravel projects successfuly in the past.
For the first time I am using Laravel 8 with Jetstream and Livewire. Laravel is now using Fortify for login and registration auth.

My local server works perfect, no issues. After deploying the project to a Hostgator shared hosting account, my homepage loads correctly and reads and outputs data from my DB correctly.

However, when I try to access

mydomain.com/login/ or mydomain.com/login
or
mydomain.com/register/ or mydomain.com/register

I get a 500 error. Below at the end of this question I am pasting the error log.

I have done the following:

1. Updated composer version
2. npm rebuild
3. npm install
4. I tried both: npm run dev and npm run production and re-uploaded everything in each scenario.
5. I have pointed public/index.php path to the correct app folder to read the autoload.php and bootstrap/app.php files.
6. I have chmod all folders and subfolders to 755 and all files to 644

I find it really strange that my homepage loads flawless and brings data from DB just fine, therefore I know that my .env file has the correct db connection credentials. Only the login and registration will throw a 500 error.

My env file:

```
APP_NAME=NameOfApp
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:KeyGeneratedWhenProjectCreated
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://domain
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_works_good
DB_USERNAME=username_works_good
DB_PASSWORD=passwordWorksGood
```

Here is the laravel.log (shortened to what seems important):

```
[2020-11-30 20:25:34] production.ERROR: The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: /domain_root_path/app/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php) (View: /domain_root_path/app/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): The Mix manifest does not exist. (View: /domain_root_path/app/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php) (View: /domain_root_path/app/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php) at /domain_root_path/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Mix.php:46)
[stacktrace]
#0 /domain_root_path/app/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/CompilerEngine.php(38): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 0)
#1 /domain_root_path/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(60): Livewire\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 0)
#2 /domain_root_path/app/vendor/livewire/livewire/src/LivewireViewCompilerEngine.php(32): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home2/usr2...', Array)
...................
#52 /domain_root_path/public_html/index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 {main}
[previous exception] [object] (Exception(code: 0): The Mix manifest does not exist. at /domain_root_path/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Mix.php:46)
[stacktrace]




#0 /domain_root_path/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(506): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Mix->__invoke('/css/app.css')
#1 /domain_root_path/app/storage/framework/views/f25b68bee7f180a7da8624828693071be98325dc.php(14): mix('css/app.css')
#2 /domain_root_path/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(107): require('/home2/usr2...')
............................................
#66 {main}
```

THE STRUCTURE OF FILES:

root has two folders:

- app (has all files except public folder)
- public_html : has all public content including index.php

My index.php (inside public) has the following paths:

```
require __DIR__.'/../app/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap/app.php';
```

GUEST.BLADE.PHP looks like this:
(please note that this file was auto-generated by Laravel and I have not touched it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.7.3/dist/alpine.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="font-sans text-gray-900 antialiased">
            {{ $slot }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

/public/mix-manifest.json:

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
}
```

Comment: Post the code for `app/resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php` this file is having an issue where you have used mix() helper

Comment: What is the public directory name? And please show us the directories structre.

Comment: I have added the guest.blade.php file content (autogenerated by laravel) and the directory structure.

Comment: This `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">` is causing the error. What are the contents of `public/mix-manifest.json` and where is the app.css file located in the public folder

Comment: Do you have any other `mix-manifest.json` in any of the sub directories in public? Also post the `webpack.mix.js` content

Comment: Your questions pointed me in the right direction. I replaced <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}"> with <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css/"> and it works now. Will this cause a problem? Must I use {{mix('css/app.css')}} ?

Comment: No it won't cause problems as such. `mix()` helper is useful for cache busting and versioning https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting . However it should work with mix() helper as well if you have your config set properly in webpack.mix.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">`

with

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css/">`

and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you read below the error there is a hint about the solution :

[Error's screenshot with a hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Tcw.png)

You missed `npm install && npm run dev`

Answer (score -1):

The error happens because of two reasons:

- you have to run `npm install && npm run dev`
- if `npm run dev` command occurs error, please upgrade your node.js version to latest.

Comment: what about when the mix code is in a package?  How do you make sure the site including the package knows how to build the mix file?